# Stop word removing went wrong

Tags: java, file, stop-words

For some IR purpouses, I would like to extract some text snippet and before analyzing, I wish to remove stop words. To do so, I made a `txt` file of stop words and then using following code, trying to remove those useless words:

```
private static void stopWordRemowal() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

Set<String> stopWords = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("StopWord.txt"));
for(String line;(line = br.readLine()) != null;)
   stopWords.add(line.trim());


BufferedReader  br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text"));
FileOutputStream theNewWords=new FileOutputStream(temp);

for(String readReady;(readReady = br2.readLine()) != null;)

    {
    StringTokenizer tokenizer =new StringTokenizer(readReady) ;
        String temp=tokenizer.nextToken();
        if(!stopWords.equals(temp))
        {   
            theNewWords.write(temp.getBytes());
            theNewWords.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
        }}

    }
```

But in fact it does not working well. Considering the following example text snippet:

```
Text summarization is the process of extracting salient information from the source text and to present that 
information to the user in the form of summary
```

the output will be like:

```
Text
summarization
is
the
process
of
extracting
salient
information
from
the
source
text
and
to
present
that
information
to
the
user
in
the
form
of
summary
```

it is almost like no effect. But I do not know why.

Comment: Please also post the StopWord.txt file. Also please note that you have problems with spacing in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method of Set and not equals method like:

```
 if(!stopWords.contains(temp))//does set contains my string temp?
```

Instead of

```
if(!stopWords.equals(temp))//set equals to string? not possible
```

Comment: oh. that was it. but why not equal? i mean, since `to` in the `stop word.txt` is equal to `to` in the file itself, why it has to be wrong to use `equals()`?

Comment: Nah you are callign equals method on set object. Set of String would be equal to another set of strings. It wont happen that set of string equals a single String.

Comment: I also would like to demand for an improvement. I was hoping if there is a way to make it case insensitive? is it using patterns or what?

Comment: One way would be to have stop words in either lowecase/upper case and then when you do contains you change the case of your tokens that you read appropriately.